# running towerjs on windows 8 gives a TypeError

Tags: windows, towerjs

I installed `tower@0.4.2-22` on my windows 8 machine. After this I tried to verify the installation. I started mongod server, the tower server and called `http://localhost:3000` in my browser. I get the error messages (in browser window and server log):
TypeError: Object Windows 8 has no method 'match'
    at Object.Tower.MiddlewareAgent [as handle] (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\lib\tower-middleware\server\agent.js:13:21)
    at next (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
    at Object.handle (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\app\config\server\bootstrap.coffee:23:14)
    at next (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
    at Object.methodOverride [as handle] (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\methodOverride.js:37:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\proto.js:199:15)
    at multipart (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\multipart.js:64:37)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:57:9)
    at urlencoded (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\urlencoded.js:51:37)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Philipp\Documents\Scripts\tower\Tests\test01\node_modules\tower\node_modules\connect\lib\middleware\bodyParser.js:55:7)

I tried to figure out what's happened and find out that in module
\node_modules\tower\lib\tower-middleware\server\agent.js
the method calls
    mac: !!agent.os.match(/mac/i),
    windows: !!agent.os.match(/win/i),
    linux: !!agent.os.match(/linux/i)
failed because agent.os is of type object and not string.
I replaced the lines with
    mac: !!agent.os.toString().match(/mac/i),
    windows: !!agent.os.toString().match(/win/i),
    linux: !!agent.os.toString().match(/linux/i)
and tower comes up and is running.

Is this a bug in the code or was something wrong with my installation?

First I installed tower with npm install power -g
Then I created a app with tower new test01
The next steps were:
- cd test01
- npm install
- forever server.js  (failed forever wasn't installed)
- npm install forever -g
- forever server.js (failed mongod wasn't started)
- (started mongodb)
- forever server.js (is running now)
- cake watch (in another prompt - failed, because grunt missing)
- npm install grunt -g
- cake watch (now it's running)
- (go to browser and enter `http://localhost:3000`)
- (see error description above)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a recent bug, probably something that has changed in recent versions of node.js or one of Tower's other depencies, I noticed tower has suddenly gotten a few bug reports for this over the past couple of days, and looks like [someone submitted a patch last night](https://github.com/viatropos/tower/pull/376)
so watch for either that pull request to get accepted or pull it into your own fork of tower.js and try again.